# AlarmManager does never work

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I see all the questions and answers but i didn't find a solution to my problema. My Alarm (or PendingIntent) is never fired. Here is my code:

**Manifest**

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".colorevent.receiver.ConfigureEventAlarmsReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":remote" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="iupix.mobile.CONFIGURE_EVENT_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Alarm creation**

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt(ConfigureEventAlarmsReceiver.EVENT_ID, 1);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfigureEventAlarmsReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}else{
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class ConfigureEventAlarmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String CONFIGURE_EVENT_ACTION = "iupix.mobile.CONFIGURE_EVENT_ACTION";

    public static final String EVENT_ID = "EVENT_ID";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(CONFIGURE_EVENT_ACTION)) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            if(extras != null) {
                if(extras.containsKey(EVENT_ID)) {
                    int eventId = extras.getInt(EVENT_ID);
                    this.configureAlarmsForEvent(context, eventId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Please, I don't know really what to do.

Thank you!

Comment: There's a difference between `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` and `RTC_WAKEUP`. Depending on which Android version you're running, the alarm that you're setting could be _way_ in the future. For that `Calendar`, use `RTC_WAKEUP` everywhere.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. My device is Kitkat and it doesn't work in Kitkat, don't know if it work in another devices with another versions

Comment: How are you determining that your Receiver isn't running? You're not setting the action on the `Intent`, so it's not going to enter the `if` block. Also, you're not actually setting any extras on the `Intent`.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the first if and in the method invocation, and the onReceive is never called

Comment: I would suggest that you put a log print - or even a `Toast` - at the top of `onReceive()` instead. Also, make sure the `<receiver>`'s `name` is pointing to the right place, and that the `<receiver>` element itself is in the right place in the manifest.

Comment: Effectively, I add a Log after onReceive() and I can see the Log in Android monitor, but the debugger never goes to the breakpoint. Thank you